# Error when trying to install nodemon on MacOS

Tags: node.js, macos, nodemon

I am trying to install `nodemon` in my Macbook. Here is the alert from terminal.

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/fsevents/.node-gyp'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.0.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node" "--module_name=fse" "--module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64" "--napi_version=5" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64 --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.0.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64 --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
```

Comment: Please add you terminal output as well.

Comment: I add the picture of it. I am new here.I don't know how to create code properly in this site.I try to create code and add terminal output to code ,when i try to submit it the site alert me that to add more some details. But i have nothing to add.

Comment: Please follow the guidelines here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You may have tried to install nodemon globally without using sudo:

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

If that's the case try installing it locally:

```
npm install nodemon
```

or use sudo to install it globally:

```
sudo npm install -g nodemon
```

Comment: I use sudo npm install -g nodemon already. But same error occur.